# "This fork looks like plastic": Grammatically right?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I understand that when we say "looks like plastic" we mean "looks like plastic material".

So I would like to know if it's correct in the grammar sense or "normal" to say "This fork looks like plastic". Because I thought we would expect something to "look like" a form of another, e.g., "looks like a cat". But plastic has no form, so I'm wondering if it's correct, though the sentence structure seems right.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it looks like [it's made of / it is] plastic. Of course the fork itself says "Looks like chicken."

Comment: This looks like trouble. (Looks like rain, "looks like meat's back on the menu, boys," "looks like the backstroke, sir...") Using "resembles __ in appearance" as a universal definition for the phrase "looks like __" breaks a lot of usages. Some are more along the lines of "appears to be __," or "appearances indicate that __".

Comment: it’s ok. You could also say “This fork looks like it’s plastic”

Comment: 'Plastic' is a standalone noun (used mainly but not solely in non-count usages) as well as the modifier (a plastic mug). 'This statue is bronze' works, though there's a deletion  ('made of') purists might object to. But 'This looks like bronze' may be the deleted form of 'This [object] looks like it's [made of] bronze' **or** it may be simply a comparative This [object] looks [like a] bronze [one would]'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct.

look like= to be similar in appearance to someone or something, to resemble (someone or something)

He looks like his father. It looks like snow.

It looks like plastic= It looks as if it has been made of plastic./It looks as if it is plastic.

It looks like rain= It looks as if it is going to rain.